# Azure CLI - Synapse linked service not accepting user assigned managed identity credential

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-synapse, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to create a Key Vault linked service in Synapse through the Azure CLI.

I use a definition file like

```json
{
    "properties": {
      "annotations": [],
      "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
      },
      "type": "AzureKeyVault",
      "typeProperties": {
        "credential": {
          "referenceName": "SynapseUserAssignedManagedIdentity",
          "type": "CredentialReference"
        },
        "baseUrl": "{baseUrl}"
      }
    }
  }
```

and use the Azure CLI like

```
az synapse linked-service create `
    --workspace-name $SynapseWorkspaceName `
    --name $LinkedServiceName `
    --file $LinkDefinition
```

where the `$LinkDefinition` is a JSON string with the definition. The `referenceName` links to a Synapse Credential `SynapseUserAssignedManagedIdentity` that was created in advance.

However, when I perform this action, the linked service ends up being created but uses the 'System Assigned Managed Identity' by default. I tried all sorts of variations to get it to work, but it always reverts to using the system assigned managed identity.

If you look at the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/linked-service/create-or-update-linked-service?tabs=HTTP#azurekeyvaultlinkedservice) the definition file does look correct, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work as expected.

Does anyone have a clue why this is not working for me?

Comment: I see the same behavior, and I am checking with Synapse PG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PG confirmed that this is a known issue, and they are in the process of fixing the issue.
ETA would be Aug 1st.